# UITableView Custon Cell not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Tried to make an table view with custom cell.
I watched few tutorials but instead of opening a new project and follow step by step.
I tried to do it with my current one. that way I can fix the problem and learn more.

So here the steps I did so far: 
Simple tableview:

[image]

(WorkoutList.xib)

WorkoutList.h (workoutTableView is the one u saw in the picture above)

[image]

WorkoutList.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.workoutTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.workoutTableView.delegate = self;

    TitleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return TitleArray.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    WorkoutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[WorkoutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.workoutTitle.text = [TitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.workoutImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list-item-icon3"];

    return cell;
}
```

WorkoutCell.xib:

[image]

Custom Class is: WorkoutCell
Identifier is: Cell

WorkoutCell.h:

[image]

All I see is just an empty TableView ..

I know its a long question, but its really important to me to understand it and see where my mistake is. Thanks a lot !

Comment: what is "not working" ? without put me to visit links pls. Describe it!

Comment: I just wrote everything about my problems, with codes and images ..

Comment: good, than you got down-voted

Comment: Did you set the class of the tableview in interface builder to your custom class?

Answer (score 1):

In your viewcontroller.h file, make sure that you add `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` in the interface like this:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Also in the .xib file select the UITableView and connect datasource and delegate to File Owner and tableView to workoutTableView like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Finally in Workoutecell xib, select file owner and add your view controller to Custom Class.

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to create .h and .m file..just create WorkoutCell.xib file..then set Tag values for UIImageview(tag 1) and UILabel(tag2) in File Inspecter(RHS) ...then write the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"WorkoutCellIdentifier";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

            // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
            if (cell == nil) {
                // Use the default cell style.
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkoutCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
            [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"]];
            UILabel *lbl=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            [lbl setText:@"your Text"];
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have TitleArray.count as if it is a property. count is a method on an array. You need to call it as shown below

```
return [TitleArray count];
```